# how to get multiple spriteNodes to jump when screen is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this line of code, to make 3 spriteNodes, i would like them to jump up the screen when I tap anywhere on the screen, but not to follow where the screen is tapped, i can get a single spriteNode to do it, using 
applyImpluse in touchBegan, i will be using the accelerometer to move x axis, any help will be greatly appreciated,

```
    let numberOfBalls = 3
    let ballWidth = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball6").size.width
    let totalBallWidth = ballWidth * CGFloat(numberOfBalls)
    ball6.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)

    let xOffset = (CGRectGetWidth(frame) - totalBallWidth)/2

    for i in 0..<numberOfBalls{
    let ball6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball6")
    ball6.position = CGPoint(x: xOffset + CGFloat(CGFloat(i) / 2) * ballWidth, y: CGRectGetHeight(frame) / 2)
    self.addChild(ball6)

        ball6.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball6.frame.size.width/2)
        ball6.physicsBody?.friction = 0.5
        ball6.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.8
        ball6.physicsBody?.mass = 0.2
        ball6.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        ball6.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        ball6.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

Comment: What happens to the other balls?

Comment: Ball6 is the name of the image saved on my desktop, and copied in to Assets.xcassets, the code above then gives me 3 balls of the same image, all the do on screen is fall to the bottom and just sit there, they move when I tilt phone left and right and bounce off each other, but tapping the screen does nothing.

Comment: I'm using this code in touchesBegan  
        Ball6.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
   Ball6.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 50))